# Executing arbitrary commands through iptables-restore input

Tags: appsec, linux, penetration-test, iptables

During a pentest I found a way to add arbitrary iptables firewall rules to a server. These rules get applied by way of the iptables-restore command, and I've been wondering whether there is any way to execute commands by manipulating the input.

My starting point is the following, which will output the help for `iptables-restore`:

```
printf '*filter\n--help\n' | iptables-restore --test
```

So I know that options are executed as expected. Now, the man page mentions a `--modprobe=command` option, which is described as:

> --modprobe=command
>
> When adding or inserting rules into a chain, use command to load any necessary modules (targets, match extensions, etc).

Great, I thought, I can execute a command by providing a non-existent target and coaxing iptables into probing for it. I've tried the following (and variants thereof):

```
printf '*filter\n--modprobe=/some/command -A INPUT -j sometarget\n' | iptables-restore --test
```

But this just gives an error without attempting to execute `/some/command`:

> iptables-restore v1.4.12: Couldn't load target `sometarget':No such file or directory

I've also tried using a module which exists but isn't currently loaded, but the module gets loaded successfully without calling the custom modprobe command.

Any hints or suggestions on where to go next (or any other routes I could investigate) would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** `--modprobe` seems to be out of the question, so the question becomes: are there any other potential exploits possible by passing malicious rules to `iptables`?

Answer (score 4):

The `--modprobe` option is part of the command line syntax of the `iptables-restore` command. It isn't something that `iptables-restore` parses as input.

So if there's a sudo rule that allows you to run `iptables-restore` with arbitrary arguments, you can pass `--modprobe=/bin/sh` or variants thereof. But if all you can do is pass input to `iptables-restore`, then this particular method doesn't allow arbitrary code execution.

Note that I do not assert that `iptables-restore` doesn't allow arbitrary code execution in some other way. In particular, if you can control the environment but not the command line options, `export MODPROBE_OPTIONS='-d ~/malicious_modules'` (in combination with a rule that triggers the loading of a module) looks promising, but I haven't tried it. And of course modifying firewall rules can cause all kinds of havoc (starting from trivial DoSes and building on from there — often services restricted to localhost would be dangerous if exposed to the whole Internet).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Interestingly, `iptables-restore` definitely parses the `--modprobe` option to some extent, because it gives the error _no command specified_ if the command argument is left out. Regarding your last point, unfortunately I can only modify the firewall rules through a web interface, so tampering with the environment isn't possible.

Comment: I stand corrected, the _no command specified_ error is coming from `iptables` itself, but `iptables-restore` is reporting it as though it were its own error. So I suppose the question becomes whether `iptables --modprobe=command` can be used to our advantage.

Comment: `modprobe` is only invoked directly to load the `ip_tables` or `ip6_tables` modules. Those modules load the others as required. As noted by Gilles, `--modprobe` isn't part of the configuration input, see the "COMMAND" section of the iptables man page for the list, which confusingly does include `-h` and `-V`. Read the `command4()` function in `iptables.c` for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what [modules are available](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/xtables-addons.8.html), you might be able to use xt_sysrq for some fun.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually quite interesting. I wasn't aware of that particular module, it's definitely worth a look; powering down the server would make a beautiful PoC!